Is it true for p=6 that any graph G = (V,E) with average degree bigger than 2p − 2 and maximum degree at most 2p − 1 contains a p-regular subgraph?
The graphs can have multiple edges but no loop.
I can't find any counterexample.
And the original problem is for any integer p.
It's well known that this assertion is true for any prime power p.
